# How do I change value in a pandas series based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series with only binary values

```
    0
0   1
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   1
5   0
6   1
7   0
8   0
9   1
10  0
11  1
12  0
13  1
14  0
```

I want to covert the value in series where it is zero and around it has one's i.e basically change 1, 0, 1 to 1, 1, 1.

Output I need is :

```
0     1
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     0
8     0
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    1
14    0
```

What I have tried here is to create a rolling window of 3 and check if the values are what I need. Is there any better way to go around doing this?

```
>>> window = df.rolling(3, center=True)
>>> (df[0] | window.apply(lambda x: 1 if (x == [1,0,1]).all() else 0)[0].fillna(0)).astype(int)
```

NOTE: I have tried shift function too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) for boolean masks and set `1` by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m1 = df[0].shift() == 1
m2 = df[0].shift(-1) == 1
m3 = df[0] == 0

df[0] = np.where(m1 & m2 & m3, 1, df[0])

print (df)
    0
0   1
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   0
8   0
9   1
10  1
11  1
12  1
13  1
14  0
```

Comment: I had used shift, but have used string concat after it. This is nice way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) to perform a centered moving window of length 3, and then check if the value of the column `0` is 0 and at the same time that the `sum` of the centered moving window at that index is 2, meaning that the surrounding samples are 1s:

```
df['window'] = df.rolling(3, center = True).sum()
idx = df[(df.window == 2.0) & (df['0'] == 0)].index.values
df.loc[idx,'0'] = 1

print(df['0'])

0     1
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     0
8     0
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    1
14    0
```

Comment: Wow! Did not even have a clue that it could be done with sum

Answer (score 1):

You can use convolutions for your specific case as well.

You can use the following filter:

```
[0.5, 0, 0.5]
```

Meaning you get a for a location only if the surrounding locations are one's.

You can then use this as an index where to change the value of the series to a 1.

```
from scipy.signal import convolve
print(df)
0     1
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     0
6     1
7     0
8     0
9     1
10    0
11    1
12    0
13    1
14    0
dtype: int64

df.iloc[convolve(df, [0.5, 0, 0.5], mode='same') == 1] = 1

print(df)

0     1
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     0
8     0
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    1
14    0
```

Did a little timing check:

```
def check_convolve(df):
    df.iloc[convolve(df, [0.5, 0, 0.5], mode='same') == 1] = 1

def check_shifts(df):
     m1 = df.shift() == 1
     m2 = df.shift(-1) == 1
     m3 = df == 0
     df = np.where(m1 & m2 & m3, 1, df[0])


%timeit check_convolve(df)
205 µs ± 22.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit check_shifts(df)
1.16 ms ± 37.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Lots of ways of doing this. But I don't want to use an extra library for just doing this. Thanks for the answer btw.